# How to ignore unused resources without delete them?

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

There's a project that have many icons of different colors, all well added to the drawable resources (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, etc), and some other resoruces like layouts and empty classes; for the firsts releases I'm not using some specific icon colors and its related activities, but I'll need to add these resources in the next releases anyway, and for update purposes maybe I have to keep ignoring some resources.

**Delete and add resources to the drawable files may be exhaustive**, so the question is:

**Is there a way to generate a release signed apk without the resources that we are not currently using?**

I tried

> Right click on app --> Refactor --> Remove Unused Resources[image]

But it's just about delete these unused resources from the entire project.

Comment: **shrinkResources** only compares if a drawable is in the folder but not in the R class.    (so try not to refer the drawable) so it will remove in build APK

Answer (score 2):

**Add this in Proguard file**

> -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

change

> proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
>   'proguard-rules.pro'

**picasso lib clearly says to add this in proguard file**

visit this https://github.com/square/picasso

**where to find Proguard file?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your proguard file proguard-rules.pro:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

And change your build.gradle to:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

After that if you still have issues with proguard is because you have to add more exclusions to your proguard-rules.

Answer (score 0):

This error has no relation with shrink resources. Its all about your proguard configs.

Sadly i cant just give you all stuff that need to be in proguard.txt. Because each dependency that you added to your project has its own proguard config. Make sure you have correct proguard config for each dependency that you added.

You can check their github wikis or any other sites for template proguards.

Good luck there

Emre